# Character encoding filter, Korean characters encoding issues

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, character-encoding

We have a Spring MVC based multi lingual web application. We have set the CharacterEncodingFilter in web.xml as mentioned below

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

with these configurations the application is working fine as expected.

When we pass this korean character from jsp "직원의상세미니", in our service layer we find this character getting encoded as "ì§ìììì¸ë¯¸ë"

we have a function of querying the jdbc metadata with the received owner name to get the tables available within that as mentioned below

```
ResultSet resultSetTables = dbMetadata.getTables(owner,owner, "%", tableTypes);
```

1) this function

```
ResultSet resultSetTables = dbMetadata.getTables("직원의상세미니","직원의상세미니", "%", tableTypes);
```

returns 7 tables available under the schema "직원의상세미니"

where as when run with the encoded string "ì§ìììì¸ë¯¸ë"

```
ResultSet resultSetTables = dbMetadata.getTables("ì§ìììì¸ë¯¸ë","ì§ìììì¸ë¯¸ë", "%", tableTypes);
```

returns 0 tables available under the same schema "직원의상세미니".

Comment: What web container you are using? When you say "pass" is that through GET? The URI encoding in the container is a good candidate to check to begin with. If that is all coming through fine, then we can check other parts of the stack.

Comment: we are using tomcat webcontainer, and the request param received from the request is "ì§ìììì¸ë¯¸ë"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Tomcat is your issue, your URI encoding may be defaulted to ISO-8859-1 in your HTTP Connector.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html, You might have to set the URIEncoding as UTF-8 and see if that helps.

I tried quickly on python console, and if I use the string you provided with iso-8859-1, I get the same gibberish as you have posted.

```
>>> a = '직원의상세미니'
>>> print a.decode("iso-8859-1")
ì§ìììì¸ë¯¸ë
```

Comment: ya that solved the problem, i already had URIEncoding="UTF-8" before but adding useBodyEncodingForURI="true" in server.xml's connector solved the problem. Thanks a lot :)